# recursive branching path query in neo4j

Tags: recursion, neo4j

I have a recursive path in neo4j that I want to be able to traverse no matter how deep the recursion is.  Each recursive path can also branch into multiple new recursive paths at any point.  The paths consist of multiple node types with multiple relationships between them.  The following is an example:

```
(item)-[:input]->(process)-[:output]->(item)-[:input]->(process)-[:output]->(item)- .....
                         |
                         --[:output]->(item)-[:input]->(process)-[:output]->(item)- ..... 
                                           |
                                           --[:input]->(process)-[:output]->(item)- .....
```

In this example, we have an item that is an input to a process.  That process produces two new items as outputs.  One of those items goes to another process that then produces another output, etc.  The other item goes to two processes that then each produce more outputs.  Each path can be of any depth, alternating between the "item" and "process" nodes connected by alternating "input" and "output" relationships. Any path can branch into multiple paths by having a process output multiple items or having a process input multiple items.

How can I effectively model and query this situation in neo4j so that I can return such a complex path?

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your use case? Your branching factor seems to be fairly low in terms of complexity. I think you've modeled it pretty well. A process can output many items and an item can be the input of many different processes. Improve your question by stating the kind of queries you are looking to perform. As in, "I want to find processes that output multiple items of XYZ type, where the items are integral to ABC processes."

Comment: Basically, I am trying to trace a value chain.  I would start with the first item and then trace through all the other processes and items that depend on that initial item.